# Can I Block Android Application on Router?

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router, internet-connection, wifi-configuration

How do I Block Android Application on Router? Example: IMO App.

> Block means, I do not want to allow this application to access my
>   internet.

***Router: TP-Link***

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You need to know what URL / IP address / Port / etc - that particular app is using, and then set up firewall rules to prevent that. You probably be better off using apps on your phone as per this answer - https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/block-apps-from-accessing-the-internet-on-android-device

Answer (score 2):

Not generally, no.

The router has no knowledge of the application, only the characteristics of the traffic passing through it.   If you can define a set of simple characteristics (like unique protocol/IP/port requirements) then it can be blocked - but this would not block the application, it would block the traffic.